# Efficiency of _reindex api by query used against large indices

Tags: elasticsearch

**Motivation**

We are currently storing a bunch of transactional/analytic user data in elasticsearch datastreams. When the users accounts are closed for whatever reason, we need to maintain their data for 30 days before deleting for recovery purposes.

To achieve this, we are thinking to create some seperate datastreams/index aliases like 'user-data-30d' and use an ILM policy to manage the lifetime of documents in this ds/alias. To migrate the user data from our active user indices into this one, We would like to use the _reindex api supplying a query for the user's guid to match against, e.g.:

```
    {
      "source": {
        "index": "usertransactions",
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "userId": "someGuid"
          }
        }
      },
      "dest": {
        "index": "usertransactions-30d",
      }
    }
```

**PROBLEM**

The source datastreams we are querying against contains on the order of ~1b documents, and initial analysis shows that we would need to run this query ~12 times per minute, with an average user containing ~100 documents that require reindexing.

My questions are:

1. Is there an easier way to manage a user's documents TTL than the approach described above in ES?
2. Does the reindex api support this kind of usage? All of the questions and documentations I have read around the _reindex api seem to suggest it is more for moving entire indices around for adding new mappings and the like. I am worried the querying part paired with how frequently we will be calling will consume too many resources on the cluster and bring it down, halting even regular ingestion.
3. How would we optimize the reindex operation with a query? For example, is it more performant to do 10 reindex operations and a simple query matching for one userId, or one reindex operation with a heavier query matching against 10 userIds?

Comment: Is exists the users TTL?

Comment: We are not setting _ttl on any documents as per its deprecation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/mapping-ttl-field.html

Comment: I meant, is your users data have some maximal time period till user close. For example: each user can use his account up to month (send transactions up to month)

Comment: I don't think so, but I might not fully understand what you mean. While users are active we keep all their data and transactions permanently. They can continue to do stuff i.e. send transactions forever. But once they close account, we want to move all their data to index with 30d ILM policy.